# .htaccess redirect with a query and a foreign language

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a URL from one format to another. The problem is that it's Hebrew, and I have a query string.

Original URL:

Example: articlename.html

Real URL: /לינה-משפחתית.html

Redirect here:

Example: ?render=articlename

Real URL: /?cat=לינה-משפחתית

Because of the ? and the Hebrew, I can't seem to get it to work...

I tried to make it work, and used these two questions as a reference but didn't manage to get it working..:

[htaccess 301 redirect with encoded hebrew URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023869/htaccess-301-redirect-with-encoded-hebrew-urls)

[htaccess 301 redirect with query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218115/htaccess-301-redirect-with-query)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The end code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/שםכאן-2-3\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAINGOESHERE/?etze_gilaim=שםכאן-2-3&q=%1 [R=302,L]
```